# Custom view presenter in WPF application

Tags: mvvmcross

I am writing a WPF application with MvvmCross. I want to have a custom view presenter. Here is what I wrote:

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxWpfViewPresenter
{
    ContentControl _contentControl;

    FrameworkElement _currentContentView;
    FrameworkElement _rootContentView;

    public ViewPresenter(ContentControl c)
    {
        _contentControl = c;

        AddPresentationHintHandler<SetRootHint>(SetRootHintHandler);
        AddPresentationHintHandler<PopToRootHint>(PopToRootHintHandler);
    }

    protected override void ShowContentView(FrameworkElement element, MvxContentPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        base.ShowContentView(element, attribute, request);

        _currentContentView = element;
    }

    private bool SetRootHintHandler(SetRootHint hint)
    {
        _rootContentView = _currentContentView;

        return true;
    }

    private bool PopToRootHintHandler(PopToRootHint hint)
    {

        return true;
    }
}
```

I am registering it in my `Setup` class:

```
public class Setup : MvxWpfSetup<Core.App>
{
    protected override IMvxWpfViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter(ContentControl root)
    {
        return new ViewPresenter(root);
    }
}
```

As soon as I try to show my first view, it crashes on this line:

```
base.ShowContentView(element, attribute, request);
```

With the message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

If I don't overried `ShowContentView`, it still crashes. And if I don't call `base.ShowContentView(element, attribute, request)` it doesn't display my view.

**EDIT**

After enabling `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in my Visual Studio environment, I can see the exception is actually coming from `mscorlib.dll` and is asking for `AsyncMethodBuilder.cs` to view the source for the call stack frame when the exception is thrown. All my nuget packages are up to date, and am running on Windows 10. I believe WPF has been deprecated as of Windows 10. My WPF project is targeting .NET 4.7.2 and my Core project is targeting .NET Standard 2.0. But I still don't know how to fix this.. I'm using the latest MvvmCross too (6.1.2.0).

**EDIT 2**

I made a small sample application with the same issue here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uROc8TYzWdx54BV8LtgCNLtwhc_MhXq3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which version of MvvmCross you're using? If it's the latest (6.1.2), I would suggest trying to turn on the Source Linking, which will let you debug mvvm cross sources and might give you better understanding of the problem. Check out [Nick's post](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/07/31/Debugging-and-Contributing-to-MvvmCross.aspx) about it. If you still can't figure out, please add some stack traces from the exception you're getting

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post.

Comment: Sorry, you need to provide more info (possibly stack traces) on what's actually happening to determine what could be the problem. WPF definitely did not get deprecated on Windows 10 though. Maybe also have a look at the [WPF playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Wpf) sample in MvvmCross github repo, to check what you might be missing. Other suggestion would be to create a simple github repro sample so I can have a look

Comment: I made a small sample application with the same issue and put the link to it in the original post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your sample application is no longer available. Can you please share it with me? I am trying to get started with MVVM Cross, but it is quite hard to find out how it all fits together above the trivial stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the sample. I was able to figure it out.

You're experiencing this issues becuase you're not calling the `base` constructor on the `ViewPresenter`. Change your `ViewPresenter` code to this:

```
public ViewPresenter(ContentControl c) : base(c)
{
    _contentControl = c;

    AddPresentationHintHandler<SetRootHint>(SetRootHintHandler);
    AddPresentationHintHandler<PopToRootHint>(PopToRootHintHandler);
}
```

That way, the [base constructor](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/c6ef1953d022585df9fb0643d786c7f510c11b15/MvvmCross/Platforms/Wpf/Presenters/MvxWpfViewPresenter.cs#L40) will be called and the `ContentControl` will be added to `_frameworkElementsDictionary`, which in turn **will not** throw an exception

> Sequence contains no elements

'cause there will be one element in it